# SOQL Query returns results, however written in SOSL it returns nothing

Tags: soql, soap-api, sosl

I am trying to find contacts by Phone number. I require using SOSL due to it's search excluding non-alphanumeric chars but cannot get the same (or any) results from SOSL as I can from SOQL. I am using the same SoapClient for each....

```
                var query = @"SELECT Phone FROM Contact WHERE Phone = '999999999'";
                queryRequest objQueryReq = new queryRequest();
                objQueryReq.queryString = query;
                objQueryReq.SessionHeader = header;
                objQueryReq.MruHeader = null;
                objQueryReq.PackageVersionHeader = null;
                queryResponse objQueryResponse = queryClient.query(objQueryReq);
                qr = objQueryResponse.result;
```

This results in the correct 2 records found. The SOSL equivalent (I must not be doing it correctly!) returns null results...

```
                searchRequest objSearchReq = new searchRequest();
                objSearchReq.searchString = "FIND {999999999}IN Phone FIELDS RETURNING Contact";
                objSearchReq.SessionHeader = header;
                objSearchReq.PackageVersionHeader = null;
                searchResponse objSearchResponse = queryClient.search(objSearchReq);
                SearchResult sr = objSearchResponse.result;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried doing your SOSL query in the Developer Console to check your syntax ia correct and you get the expected results?

Comment: Yep just tried it and the query "FIND {999999999} IN Phone FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Name)" is working in dev console. Can you look at the second bit of code and see if anything stands out?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that in .net I was loading the wsdl as a "Service Reference". This was fine for SOQL but doing so for SOSL it flat out did not work, response being no returned records.

> If you want to use SOSL load the wsdl as a "Web Reference" - Add Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference

Salesforce should sort this out or at least document how exactly to do it if it is possible, Ive emailed them.